# Breakpoints in Script Task

Tags: visual-studio-2005, ssis, breakpoints

Why are the breakpoints set in Script Tasks of SSIS package (VS2005) being ignored??
I created a new package, added one simple Script Task to it, and no matter where I set the breakpoints in that task, they are being ignored.  Help please!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be a known bug and there are several workarounds, depending on how you are running the package and what's going on in the background.  This thread has a lot of good information about it:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/710c4865-bc74-4f1d-a3b9-865109ee25c7/

Hope it has something that will work for you!

Comment: It does, thank you! According to that thread, breakpoints only work when running the entire package, not individual tasks, and I was trying to debug an individual tasks. Thankfully, this crazy issue was fixed in 2008!  Thank you, DKnight!

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the breakpoint while you were still in Debug mode?  I've done that often. If you add the breakpoint while in debug mode, click 'Stop Debugging', and then run the package in Debug mode again, the breakpoint will be ignored.

Make sure you are not still in debug mode when you add the breakpoint.

Comment: Thanks, but I am definitely not in debug mode when I am adding the breakpoints.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they are being ignored, the only way I know of to get any debug information is using the MessageBox.Show() method.

Comment: There is no MessageBox.Show(), but I do currently use MsgBox to get the debug information.   Are the breakpoints really just being ignored??   I thought maybe I was missing some configuration setting or something..

Comment: @Tamila the MessageBox class is in the System.Windows.Forms namespace.

Comment: MsgBox does the same thing.  Anyway, that really doesn't solve the issue of breakpoints.. )